# wordpress ajax for a plugin only works when defined in the active theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm testing with very simple code to try and get ajax working from within a plugin I'm writing.  However I always get the dreaded 0 returned from the admin-ajax.php file.

The basic code defined in my plugins main php file is:

```
// Init custom actions
add_action( 'wp_ajax_import_run', 'import_run' );

function import_run() {
echo "testing 123";
die();
}
```

And then import_run is the action parameter parsed via the jquery ajax call.

Now the funny thing is, this works fine when I place the above php code in the themes main function.php file, but whenever I place the code in the actual plugin where it's needed it won't work.   The issue is it needs to be in the plugin, not the theme.

So it seems I'm missing some small vital step about where to put my add action and function within the plugin.   Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Is the code at the global scope - i.e. not embedded in any function? 2. How do you know your plugin actually loaded?

Comment: Impossible to say if you show only this fragment... Looks like you don't know this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just looked at wp-settings.php. Plugins are included then some irrelevant things (with respect to your code) are done and the theme functions.php is included. So basically the plugin code and the functions.php code are functionally equivalent. So my guess is your code is not even being executed.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't provided your complete code in your plugin.

You can't invoke plugin function using wp ajax call.

Here's a simple WP plugin code to display some text everywhere.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Testplugin
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Testplugin
Plugin URI: someuri
Description:  To demo a simple plugin
Version: 2.5.8
Author: Automattic
Author URI: http://automattic.com/wordpress-plugins/
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

function pluginnamehere() {
echo "This gets displayed everywhere";

}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'pluginnamehere' );
```

Comment: @ Mahesh Budeti "You can't invoke plugin function using wp ajax call." Are you sure this is what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what was going on. I was adding the add_action hook everywhere but in the core root plugin page.  Previously I had been adding it to a secondary php file that I thought was the root plugin file but wasn't.

The confusion occurred because I'm using a boilerplate empty plugin template to work with, so even though the plugin does very little so far its actually full of code and remarks already.